# How to load custom wp_customize wordpress only if has activation/license key plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, license-key

i tried to create plugin that will load custom `wp_customize` setting on my current theme.

My plan is all my custom `wp_customize` setting will not display before license key validate. for the server license plugin i use software license manager.

i had try use code to check license key validate.

```
'$api_params = array(
    'slm_action' => 'slm_check',

    'secret_key' => MYPLUGIN_CUSTOMIZER_PLUGIN_SECRET_KEY,

    'license_key' => get_option('my_license_key'), //replace with your license key field name.

);
// Send query to the license manager server
$response = wp_remote_get(add_query_arg($api_params, MYPLUGIN_CUSTOMIZER_PLUGIN_SERVER_URL), array('timeout' => 20, 'sslverify' => false));

$license_data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
global $active, $message;
if($license_data->result == 'success' && $license_data->status == 'active'){ ?>
    <script>alert('Activated');</script>
<?php }else{ ?>
          <script>alert('Deactivated');</script>
<?php } 
?>
```

Result is working and i get an alert Activated, but when i change the script alert to do action, code below :

```
if($license_data->result == 'success' && $license_data->status == 'active'){ 
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'myplugin_customizer_running' ) ); }
```

please check my full code here https://pastebin.com/Rm5T7s19

Please help how to make it this work, this is my first plugin with license key so still learning. Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure when you put alert it shows you "Activated" ? because its shows me "Deactivated" ?

Comment: hello @Jalpa, yes i am sure. Please check this [link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/4476/uJYhUZ.jpg)

Comment: Where is you "custom_customizer_running" method or function ?

Comment: sorry that wrong, should be myplugin_customizer_running, if you check my full code in pastebin, that is the correct one

Comment: What stops me from editing your code and setting `$license_data->result` to always return `success` ?

Comment: hello @DainisAbols have you installed software license manager as the server key license?

Comment: thanks for all, issue alrdy solved and it's working like what i want :)